# Return Image From Web Url without Webview

Tags: java, image, url, javafx, webview

I need to make a preview of a website , I should pass the url (e.g `http://www.google.com`) and then  want to return an Image that I will use on ImageView to make the preview. I already did this using the webview object , following this GIT `https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5632958`, but I don't know how to get an Image from webUrl without using the WebView object.

any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 0):

you can load the image in ImageView with volley. see this page for more information:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800

Comment: Hey, thanks for contributing. but unfortunately this question is about imageview and webview of JavaFX and not Android..